# To find the $n$th term of a Geometric progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, geometric-series

$a, b,$ and $c$ numbers are making geometric progression, whereas $$(a + 2b), (2a + b + c), (a + 3b + c)$$ numbers are making arithmetic progression.

How can I find the $n$th term of the above G.P

Comment: Can you edit into your question what you have tried so far?

Comment: perhaps you would like to show us what you tried?

Comment: Incidentally, you seem to have two equations and three unknowns, and it looks as if you could rescale $a,b,c$ by a constant multiplicative factor, so I would expect the answer to be a function of $a$ and $n$

Comment: $+1$ welcome to [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) though it's your first question on MSE it is expected to show the efforts you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a+2b, 2a+b+c, a+3b+c = u-d, u, u+d$$
$$\color{red}{(u-d)} + \color{blue}{u} + \color{green}{(u+d)} = 3\color{blue}{u} = \color{red}{(a+2b)}+\color{blue}{(2a+b+c)}+\color{green}{(a+3b+c)}$$
sum of three terms of AP : $3u = 4a+6b+2c = 3(2a+b+c) \implies \color{red}{3b = 2a+c}$

$a, b,c $  in G.P $$\implies \frac{c}{b} = \frac b{a} = r$$ $$\color{red}{r^2 = \frac c{a}}$$
$$\color{red}{b^2 =ac}$$
$$\left(\frac{2a+c}{3}\right)^2 = ac$$
$$\left(\frac{2+(\frac{c}{a})}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{c}{a} = r^2 = p$$
$$\left(\frac{2+p}3\right)^2 = p$$
$$\implies p = 1, 4$$
$$r = ±1, ±2$$

Comment: So u is (2a + b + c) ? and what is d?

Comment: The answer is right tho.

Comment: Yes, I know that but if u = (2a+b+c) then what d is equal to? And I don't understand how this is equal "sum of three terms of AP : 3u=4a+5b+2c=3(2a+b+c)⟹3b=2a+c"                I guess there is a need of 6b but still how do we get rest?

Comment: Ok,now I get that. But how you have factored this out "4a+5b+2c = 3(2a+b+c)" ?  I don't see how they are equal

Comment: Thank you very much!!!